# CountDownTimer with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have a RecyclerView with let say 10 items. Now I want to start a count down timer on a item by clicking on that item, till here it is working fine but when I scroll up my RecyclerView to last position than that count down timer is started on last item also but I want to start only for those items on which I click. Any help would be appreciated.
Following is my code :

public class OrdersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ClickListener mListener;
private Context mContext;

private Handler handler;
private List<Integer> countList = new ArrayList<>();

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long time;
private final long interval = 1000;

public OrdersListAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> countList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.countList = countList;
}

@Override
public OrderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_orders_list, parent, false);
    return new OrderHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final OrderHolder holder, final int position) {
    final long time = 10*60*1000;
    holder.mCardView.setTag( holder );
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                OrderHolder holder =  (OrderHolder) view.getTag();
                if (countList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()) == 0) {
                    countList.set(holder.getAdapterPosition(), 1);
                    startTimer(holder, time);
                }
                mListener.onOrderClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public class OrderHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private CardView mCardView;
    private TextView mTimer;

    public OrderHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTimer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onOrderClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.mListener = clickListener;
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onOrderClick(int position);
}

public void startTimer(OrderHolder holder, long time) {
    //time = 20*60*1000;
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(holder, time, interval);
    countDownTimer.start();
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    OrderHolder holder;

    public MyCountDownTimer(OrderHolder holder, long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        String time = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d",
                (millisUntilFinished % 3600) / 60, (millisUntilFinished % 60));
        holder.mTimer.setText(time);
    }
}
```

}

OnClick event in Activity

```
mAdapter.setClickListener(new OrdersListAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOrderClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Paste your adapter code if possible where you are handling your item's click event.

Comment: I have posted click event code

Comment: Can you describe more specific what kind of problem you are facing of?

Comment: Let's say I have clicked on the 1st item of the list than timer has started on 1st item 09:59, 09:58 etc but now if I scroll up my recyclerview than the same is running on the 2nd last item of the recyclerview, so thats the issue I am facing

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                if (countList.get(holder.getPosition()) == 0) {
                    countList.set(holder.getPosition(), 1);
                    startTimer(holder.getPosition(), time);
                }
                mListener.onItemClick(holder.getPosition());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: not working. BTW holder.getPosition is deprecated, I have used holder.getAdapterPosition() also but not working

Comment: @Krishna Meena We can't help unless we know what your are doing in your Listener's itemClick and other things.So pls update your code completely so that one can help.